# Perl script for extracting data

Tags: perl

I have a file like this as shown below.

```
chr10   299448  299468  SRR048973.1457734       255     +       3
chr10   299448  299468  SRR048973.2114188       255     +       3
chr10   299448  299468  SRR048973.4148128       255     +       3
chr10   299945  299971  SRR048973.566192        255     +       6
chr10   299959  299982  SRR048973.762883        255     +       6
chr10   299968  299985  SRR048973.1595367       255     +       6
chr10   299968  299985  SRR048973.2828877       255     +       6
chr10   299968  299985  SRR048973.3711952       255     +       6
chr10   299968  299985  SRR048973.3821978       255     +       6
chr10   300073  300095  SRR048973.975870        255     +       1
chr10   300109  300134  SRR048973.1500469       255     +       1
chr10   300185  300209  SRR048973.655183        255     +       8
chr10   300185  300209  SRR048973.933425        255     +       8
chr10   300185  300209  SRR048973.963046        255     +       8
chr10   300185  300209  SRR048973.3506573       255     +       8
chr10   300185  300209  SRR048973.3627590       255     +       8
chr10   300186  300209  SRR048973.1133369       255     +       8
chr10   300186  300209  SRR048973.2178421       255     +       8
chr10   300186  300209  SRR048973.4047933       255     +       8
chr10   300401  300426  SRR048973.918503        255     +       2
chr10   300401  300426  SRR048973.2870188       255     +       2
```

Looking at the last column, if the last column is >= 5 then I want to count the lines till the column is greater than 5 until it falls back to < 5. Also the output I want should be like this for sample file

```
chr10   299945  299985   6
chr10   300185  300209   8
```

299945 comes from the 2nd column where the first 6 starts and 299985 comes from 3rd column where the last 6 ends. Similarly for 8.

I want to do this in Perl.

I tried writing the Perl script but cannot understand how to get coordinates properly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl-w
use strict;
use warnings;

open F,'/user/tmp/output.bed',or die $!;

my $i=0;
while(<F>){
        chomp;
        my @s = split;
        if($s[6] >= 5){
                $i++;
        }else{
                if($s[6] < 5){
                $i = 0;
                }
        }

}
```

How can I do it.

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: Please paste what you have tried.

Comment: Well, you could iterate through the lines, split at spaces and use some global variable to remember if the last line had a 5 or not...

Comment: @Jithin I pasted what I tried as of now. Its just a little tricky to think.

Comment: @DeVadder How to declare that variable that remembers last line had 5 or not

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`range operator`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @last;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @cols = split ' ';
    if (my $range = $cols[-1] >= 5 .. $cols[-1] < 5 || eof) {
        @last = @cols[0..2,-1] if $range == 1;
        print "@last\n" if $range =~ /E/;
        $last[2] = $cols[2];
    }
}


__DATA__
chr10   299448  299468  SRR048973.1457734       255     +       3
chr10   299448  299468  SRR048973.2114188       255     +       3
chr10   299448  299468  SRR048973.4148128       255     +       3
chr10   299945  299971  SRR048973.566192        255     +       6
chr10   299959  299982  SRR048973.762883        255     +       6
chr10   299968  299985  SRR048973.1595367       255     +       6
chr10   299968  299985  SRR048973.2828877       255     +       6
chr10   299968  299985  SRR048973.3711952       255     +       6
chr10   299968  299985  SRR048973.3821978       255     +       6
chr10   300073  300095  SRR048973.975870        255     +       1
chr10   300109  300134  SRR048973.1500469       255     +       1
chr10   300185  300209  SRR048973.655183        255     +       8
chr10   300185  300209  SRR048973.933425        255     +       8
chr10   300185  300209  SRR048973.963046        255     +       8
chr10   300185  300209  SRR048973.3506573       255     +       8
chr10   300185  300209  SRR048973.3627590       255     +       8
chr10   300186  300209  SRR048973.1133369       255     +       8
chr10   300186  300209  SRR048973.2178421       255     +       8
chr10   300186  300209  SRR048973.4047933       255     +       8
chr10   300401  300426  SRR048973.918503        255     +       2
chr10   300401  300426  SRR048973.2870188       255     +       2
```

Outputs:

```
chr10 299945 299985 6
chr10 300185 300209 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need that counting? Your output seems to not incorporate it...

Using your code sample:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl-w
use strict;
use warnings;

open F,'/user/tmp/output.bed',or die $!;

my $i=0;
my $wasTheLastGreaterThan5 = 0;
while(<F>){
    chomp;
    my @s = split;
    if(($s[6] >= 5) && !$wasTheLastGreaterThan5){
        # Switched from smaller to greater than 5, do something here.

        $wasTheLastGreaterThan5 = 1;

    }elsif(($s[6] < 5) && $wasTheLastGreaterThan5){
        # switched from greater to smaller, do something here.

        $wasTheLastGreaterThan5 = 0;

    }
    else {
        # Did not switch, if you need to count, you could do so here.
    }
}
```